# Connect two different ubuntus running on different machines and different networks

Tags: networking, apt, ssh

So, my aunt bought a pc running Ubuntu to my grandmother (just because it was cheaper), but my grandmother doesn't even know what a command line is. I wanted to know if there's a way I could run sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade and/or access the update manager on her machine from my laptop also running Ubuntu (both using the 16.04 release, and connected to different networks, her pc on her house and my laptop on mine).

If there's a way, could anyone please explain or send a tutorial step-by-step, (from connectig on her pc until running the commands)? I read that one possibility is using ssh, but I don't know how to do it, I'm kind of a beginner in Ubuntu, so I would be very happy if someone could help :)

Comment: Your assumptions seem flawed. Talk to your grandmother and ask her what she wants. It's HER system. Do NOT install a backdoor on her system without her explicit permission - she has the same right to privacy on her system that you have on your system. Use your favorite  Search Engine to look for connection tutorials - they are everywhere. Warning: As a beginner, you may easily and erroneously break her system or leave it vulnerable to intrusion, so think about how to prevent those consequences.

Comment: Next time you are over at her place, install TeamViewer (www.teamviewer.com). It has an install for Ubuntu. You can then remote desktop into her computer.

Comment: In 10 years of maintaining Ubuntu systems for several older relatives, I used Teamviewer and similar exactly twice, neither in the past 5 years. We found it simpler and easier to do basic maintenance during occasional family visits.

Comment: @user535733 she asked me to have this access to her computer so I don't have to go to her house every time something goes wrong, I explained what I was going to try with TeamViewer and she agreed. And it worked out, I didn't break her system.

Comment: Fantastic to see that it worked out well for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty easy way to do this is to use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/teamviewer/). It gives you direct access to the your grandma's screen, mouse and keyboard. It also solves for you issues like dynamic IP allocation and firewalls - you don't even need to know what they mean.

If for any reason you prefer more hands-on approach, you can set up a VNC server and client as an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?license=opensource&platform=linux). The end result would be pretty similar, even if you have to setup everything on your own.

Another way is to [provide SSH access](https://dev.to/zduey/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-server-on-a-home-computer) to your grandma's machine. Then with `ssh <grandmas-ip>` (obviously making a substitution for the <..> part) you can log in to your grandma's console (i.e. text-only access) remotely from your machine.

Comment: It worked fine with TeamViewer thank you very much :)